# How to come off the black list in India

Tags: visa-refusals, india

I am German and was blacklisted December 2018 at the Chennai Airport without any explanation.
I had founded a Trust in Germany to support children coming from very poor rural Areas in South India (35 children, Sponsors offering 10-15.-€/month/child).

As I found out later the mistake was sending the money directly to our Indian workers, instead of sending the money to an Indian Trust with FCRA number. I resigned from the Trust and our German Trust joined with an Indian Trust with FCRA number. I have contacted the Ministry of Home Affairs several times as well as the Bureau of Immigration New Delhi, the Indian Embassy in Berlin and the Indian Consulate in Frankfurt.
So far no reply.
Do you have any suggestion how to proceed further?

Would it be counterproductive to approach an Indian Lawyer? Or do you happen to know an Indian Lawyer specified in the matter?

I would be so grateful for any advice or help!!

Comment: Some users here may be able to provide you with some general advice, but this sounds like the type of situation where you should contact a lawyer rather than relying on advice found online. We can't recommend you a specific lawyer, but  you should find one who specialises in matters of Indian immigration law.

Comment: The German consulate(s) in India may be able to recommend lawyers who specialise in this area.

Comment: Very good suggestions! Thanks alot!!!